# Add ScrollView as parent of CollectionView in iOS(Xamarin)

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview, xamarin-studio

I an new to iOS and Xamarin. I have Created one `CollectionView`. which is work fine. But It take Full Screen of the `View`. But Now I want set it Inside `TableView` with `Fix Height` and make `Horizontal` scroll. I try lot of thing but nothing could help me.

**ViewController Code :** (for CollectionView)

```
protected ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
            layout = new UICollectionViewFlowLayout
              {
                SectionInset = new UIEdgeInsets(20, 5, 5, 5),
                MinimumInteritemSpacing = 5,
                MinimumLineSpacing = 5,
                ItemSize = new SizeF(100, 100)

            };

            collectionView = new UICollectionView(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds, layout);
            collectionView.ContentSize = new CGSize(View.Frame.Size.Width, View.Frame.Size.Height);
            collectionView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
            source = new UICollectionViewDataSource();

            collectionView.RegisterClassForCell(typeof(TextCell), TextCell.CellId);
            collectionView.Source = source;

        }
```

**My Requirement :**

To make `TableView` and add the `CollectionView` as subView with fix Height of `150`.

Any Help be Appreciated.

Comment: In `TableView` create two sections, the first section contains 1 cell with `CollectionView` (define a custom `TableViewCell` with `CollectionView` in it). Second section will be your normal `TableView`.

Comment: @New16 can you explain breif I don't get it ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches here, i.e

1) Define a `UIViewController`, This approach makes sure that the
    `CollectionView` is always visible even if you try to scroll the
    `TableView`.

- Add `CollectionView` as subview to the `ViewController`'s view at
  required location.
- Add `TableView` as subview to the    `ViewController`'s view below
  the `CollectionView`.

2) Define a UIViewController, the CollectionView will disappear once your start scrolling

- Add TableView as subview to the `ViewController`.
- return 2 for `numberOfSections`.
- return 1 for `numberOfRowsInSection` for section 1
- return required number of cells for `numberOfRowsInSection` for section 2
- Define a custom TableViewCell, with CollectionView as property in this class.
- `cellForRowAtIndexPath` for `[0,0]` `IndexPath` return the custom cell.

Comment: I implement the 1 Approch but i do it like this way 1.) Create ViewController 2.) Add TableView as SubView of ViewController 3.) Add CollectionView as SubView of TableView. Is this right Approch or not ??

Comment: Never add CollectionView as subview to TableView. There will be two scroll views. Since both inherit from the ScrollView. So, its better to keep both separate. Add both as subview to the ViewController's view.

Comment: Ok Wait I implement your approch. And come back to you.

Comment: Can you tell how to give fix `Height` to `CollectionView` as you can see in  my question.

Comment: How are you adding the `CollectionView` to the view. You can set it there.